# How to unpack the tuple return value from Enum in swift

Tags: swift, enums

I would like to create a Enum that return a tuple value. When I used, I do something like  `let firstName = myType.name.first` to get the first value. However any way I can just unpack the enum so I do not need to get first and last into 2 line of code?
maybe something like

```
let (firstName, lastName) = myType.name
```

my code

```
enum SomeType {
    case type1
    case type2

    var name: (firstName: String, lastName: String) {
       switch self {
       case .type1:
            return ("type1 first", "type1 last")
        case .type2:
            return ("type2 first", "type2 last")
       }
    }
}

let myType = SomeType.type1
let firstName = myType.name.first
let lastName = myType.name.last
```

Comment: Your current code *already* allows you to do `let (firstName, lastName) = myType.name`. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you need both values, then destructuring them like you showed is the correct appraoch, and works just fine:

```swift
let (firstName, lastName) = SomeType.type1.name
print(firstName, lastName)
```

If you only need one of the tuple members, but not both, you can access with dot syntax, using either their index (less clear):

```swift
print(SomeType.type1.0)
```

or their tuple member label, if any (more clear):

```swift
print(SomeType.type1.firstName)
```

Although often it's more idiomatic to still use destructring, but just discarding the unused values with `_`:

```swift
let (firstName, _) = SomeType.type1.name

print(firstName)
```